# Good SAT learning resources?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, reference-request, self-learning

I'm looking to brush up on SAT math.  (That's basic algebra, probability and trigonometry.)

I'm interested in books and websites.

Comment: I was going to downvote because the question is not interesting (would not lead to interesting answers etc..) but I decided not to since the results could be useful to you, that might be why it was downvoted though.

Comment: Is there something wrong with all the usual SAT books (i.e. Barrons, Princeton Review, Kaplan)? Is your goal to know the material well enough to take the SAT or just to learn the material? The answer to your question might be different depending on what your plans are.

Comment: @Moshe You should spend more time on places like Khan Academy, this site, Art of Problem Solving, and Brilliant.org and learn more Math rather than worrying about SAT. The SAT will follow after you learn Math. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly reccomend the Princeton Review series of prep books, they have worked wonders for me. The College Board website also has a lot of useful tools, such as a complete free test that you can take online, and sample questions.
http://sat.collegeboard.com/practice

Comment: If you don't mind, I'm just curious what your score was. ;-)

Comment: Just know that the most important thing to work on is the time you take on the test. Those exams are all timed, so just follow the rules and you'll be good to go. You're gonna have to put in a good amount of time if you want to do well, but these resources will do the most for you in the least amount of time. An alternative if you need more materials is to just take a prep book or two from your public or school library, copy the pages, and work from there.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with SAT, as I'm not from USA, but you might find this useful: http://www.khanacademy.org/

My guess is that this guy explains all of the subjects you might need. It might lack exercises though, but it might be worth checking it out if you need to review a subject.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the new kid on the block: https://lemmaprep.com. All substantive content matter questions are answered directly by the Lemma staff.